# como guardar fecha en java

Tags: java, imagen, date

Estoy realizando un proyecto en **java netbeans** pero no puedo guardar la fecha en mi base de datos me pueden ayudar gracias este es el código que utilizo:

```
if(txtgenerico.getText().length()==0
            ||txtcomercial.getText().length()==0||txtforma.getText().length()==0||txtconcentracion.getText().length()==0||txtcantidad.getText().length()==0||fechavenc.getDate().getDate()==0||txtmarca.getText().length()==0||txtlote.getText().length()==0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "faltan datos por ingresar \n"+"Completelos Todos Por Favor" );
        }else{
            try{
                ResultSet rst;
                ConexionBD cc=new ConexionBD();
                Statement stmtr;
                try (Connection cn = cc.conexion()) {
                    stmtr = cn.createStatement();
                    rst = stmtr.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM insumos WHERE generico = '"+txtgenerico.getText()+"'");
                    if(rst.next()){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Este producto ya existe");
                    }else{
                        stmtr.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO insumos (generico, comercial, formafarma, concentracion, cantidad, fechaVenc, marca, numero_lote)"
                                + "VALUES ('"+txtgenerico.getText()+"','"+txtcomercial.getText()+"'"
                                + ",'"+txtforma.getText()+"','"+txtconcentracion.getText()+"','"+txtcantidad.getText()+"','"+fechavenc.getDate().getDate()+"','"+txtmarca.getText()+"','"+txtlote.getText()+"')");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "registro exitoso");
                        limpiar(); bloquear(); 
                    }
                }
                stmtr.close();
                rst.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.printf("Error aqui: "+ e.toString());
            }
        }
```

En la base de dato MYsql, fecha es un `DATE`. Gracias y como guardar imágenes en este mismo lenguaje con su ruta.

Comment: Que error es el que obtienes?
Es probable que el formato que intentas guardar no sea compatible con el formato que acepta la base de datos.

Comment: Explica qué tipos de dato tienen los parámetros de entrada.

Comment: el error en un truncado porque no me guarda la fecha no es compatible lo que debo de guardar en la base de datos

Answer (score 1):

Un ejemplo de como insertar fechas. Primero es importante que uses PreparedStatement para que el codigo sea mas eficiente y ademas evitar ataques de SQLInjection en queries inlines.

```
        Connection con;
        try {
            //Esta linea no tiene efecto ya que getConnection no pasa un parametro real de conexion. Es a modo ilustrativo para conseguir la conexion.
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("..............");
            //obtengo de la conexion prepareStatmen asociado a un insert. El caracter ? indica que ahi vas a insertar datos con el uso de prepareStatmen.
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into usuarios(ID, nombre, fecha)values(?,?,?)");
            //En este ejemplo en el primer ? voy a insertar un ID tipo int.
            stmt.setInt(1, 101);//1 specifies the first parameter in the query  
            //En el segundo ? voy a insertar un tipo String para el nombre
            stmt.setString(2, "Ratan");
            //Y en el tercer ? voy a insertar la fecha.
            Calendar fecha = Calendar.getInstance();
            //Convierto Calendar al tipo sql.date.
            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(fecha.getTimeInMillis());
            //indico la fecha en formato sql.date.
            stmt.setDate(3, sqlDate);
            int i = stmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(i + " reg afectados");
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewClass3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor en estos casos es usar un `PreparedStatement` ya que el mismo objeto se encarga de hacer el cast de objetos, en tu caso para la fecha.

Un ejemplo sería así para tu caso:

```
ConexionBD cc=new ConexionBD();
Connection con = cc.cc.conexion()

String sql = "INSERT INTO insumos (generico, comercial, formafarma, concentracion, cantidad, fechaVenc, marca, numero_lote)" 
           + "VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
//Se añadirian los diferentes campos en los parametros dependiendo del tipo de campo
pstm.setString(1, txtgenerico.getText());
pstm.setString(2, txtcomercial.getText());
pstm.setString(3, txtforma.getText());
pstm.setString(4, txtconcentracion.getText());
pstm.setString(5, txtcantidad.getText());
pstm.setDate(6, fechavenc.getDate());
pstm.setString(7, txtmarca.getText());
pstm.setString(8, txtlote.getText());

pstm.executeUpdate();
```

Para casos de numéricos se podría usar `pstm.setInt` o `pstm.setBigDecimal` por ejemplo. Ya sería mirar la documentación del `PreparedStatement` para cada caso que te hiciera falta.

Espero haberte ayudado! Un saludo!

Comment: gracias hermano lo pondre en practica

Comment: puedes votar la respuesta como correcta para futuros usuarios que pudiesen necesitar lo mismo que tu. Un saludo!

Comment: buenas hermanos necesito una ayuda u orientación necesito hacer en mysql y luego en un programa en java netbeans el cual me detecte quien es invitado y quien es administrador del programa 
¿como debo de hacer la base de datos y como lo llevo a código java en netbeans? 
De veras necesito esta orientación de parte de ustedes soy nuevo en esto de la programación y mas en java  gracias

Comment: Simplemente debes poner el código java dentro de una clase del proyecto de NetBeans. Para clasificar los usuarios en tu tabla de usuarios debes incluir un tipo de usuario y ahi ya clasificas los usuarios y los admins.

Comment: hermano podrías darme un ejemplo de guía y disculpa las molestias